# JQuery Locally Stored Values for RadioButtons missing Values for Postback

Tags: jquery, razor, radio-button, local-storage, postback

I wonder if someone can help me with my issue where I have some RadioButtons which are dynamically refreshed, but if someone edits these I want to retain the values if the content is refreshed again.  So far I have a working solution up until I save the form, where the RadioButton values are lost.

Let me explain:

On our form, the content is fetched each time a Role Criteria radio button is checked.

If a user makes some selections of radio buttons and comment text within the content this is the lost if the user decides to add an extra Role Criteria.  Note that there are many radio buttons and comments fields on this page, and they change depending on selection.

To correct this I added some jQuery to store the values of RadioButtons and Comments in Local Storage then repopulate the values once the context area is redrawn.  The radio buttons in question are created in a Partitial View (MVC) using Razor, on page they appear like this:
*- Note the values True & False.*

```
        <td class="text-center">
                <label class="text-center" id="lblCourseApplicableYes">
                    <input name="CourseApplicable" id="CourseApplicableYes" type="radio" checked="checked" value="True">
                    <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                </label>
                <label class="text-center” id="lblCourseApplicableNo">
                    <input name="CourseApplicable" id="CourseApplicableNo" type="radio" value="False">
                    <label for="No">No</label>
            </label>
        </td>
```

This is the basic call I use to store and restore the selections of the user and works visually as I expect:

Called before the AJAX fires to update the content:

```
function StoreValues() {
     window.localStorage.clear();
     $("#UpdatePanel").each(function () {
         var textFields = $(this).find('input[type=text], textarea');
         var radioButtons = $(this).find('input:radio');
         if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
             textFields.val(function () {
                 localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
             });
             radioButtons.val(function () {
                 if ($(this).prop("checked")) {

                     localStorage.setItem(this.id, true);
                 }
             });
         }
     });
 }
```

Called after the AJAX call redraws the content on a Successful call:

```
function RestoreValues() {
     $("#UpdatePanel").each(function () {
         var textFields = $(this).find('input[type=text], textarea');
         var radioButtons = $(this).find('input:radio');
         if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
             textFields.val(function () {
                 if (localStorage.getItem(this.id) !== null) {
                     return localStorage.getItem(this.id);
                 }
             });
             radioButtons.val(function () {
                if (localStorage.getItem(this.id) !== null) {

                    $(this).click(function() {
                        $(this).prop("checked", true);                       
                    });

                    $(this).click();
                }
             });
         }
     });
 }
```

This is works well and the user is none the wiser.  However on save things are a little different.  Once the Postback is happening the values of the Radio buttons is lost.  I need to use these so I can use Form.Request to pick up the values.

Looking at Fiddler the parameters sent back to the server are the RadioButton names, but the values are empty.

TextComments go through so I know its something to do with how the radiobutton is being checked.  If I save a fresh form without the JQuery repopulating anything then all values are as they should be, i.e radiobutton name value is True or False.

However after the JQuery restores the items, the value parameter on each input is “” blank, I notice the checked value doesn’t move either, but not sure this does normally either.  I’ve tried to force the value in there with a  bit more JQuery but haven’t had any luck, whatever I’ve tried.

I’ve tried setting these items manually to try and force it to have a value, without success.

Whats going on, can anyone help?  Testing has been generally in IE11 as that’s the company standard (don’t ask) but the behaviour appears to be the same in Chrome, so I don't think it's browser related.

Comment: `$("#updatePanel").each()` doesn't make much sense. `.each()` is for looping over multiple elements, but IDs should be unique so there's no need to loop.

Comment: Wasn't sure how else to achieve having the proceeding function run only under that 'updatepanel' element.  But I understand why it doesn't seem logical.

    $("#UpdatePanel").each(function () { etc......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `radioButtons.val()`, which sets the values of the radio buttons. But the function doesn't return anything, so the values are set to an empty string.

Also, you need to remove the unchecked radio button IDs from `localStorage` when you're saving. Otherwise, you won't forget that you previously checked a button. So the code in `StoreValues` for the radio buttons should be:

```
radioButtons.each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.id, true);
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.id);
    }
});
```

You also should be calling `.each()` rather than `.val()` for the text items.

And creating a `click` handler just to check the button seems unnecessary. In `RestoreValues` just write:

```
radioButtons.prop("checked", function() {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.id) !== null;
});
```

Comment: The click event was to handle the validation as 'yes' and 'no' have different colour backgrounds depending on selection.

Comment: You should create that event handler globally, not when restoring values.

Comment: All working quite well so thank you.

There is a small issue in that if you switch off the options that display a course then switch them back on the radio buttons are blank.  Also on first load of a form they are blank.  But the DB (default value is Yes) has values in it so they are populated then overwritten somehow when this method is evoked.  Anyway to change this so it only updates the radiobuttons that are specified in local storage...it seems like if not in storage then this is blanking them. @Barmar